# socket возвращает b'fff\n' как почистить

Tags: python

нужно что-бы в строке было только fff

Comment: пример кода пишите

Comment: `b` это просто указание на бинарные данные. и в конце еще перевод каретки. перевод каретки отрезаете явно, если он вам не нужен. И если вам нужна строка, то из бинарных данных она обычно получается через decode().

Comment: Прочитайте про форматирование текста в python, регулярные выражения. [регулярки](https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/), [форматирование данных](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/ispolzovanie-tekstovyh-strok-python/formatirovanie-strok-pechati-sohranenija/)

Comment: `b'fff\n'.decode().rstrip("\n")`